# Configuring nginx server to handle requests from multiple domains

Tags: apache-2.2, php, nginx, proxy, amazon-s3

**Use Case:-** I am working on a web application which allows to create HTML templates and publish them on amazon S3.Now to publish the websites I use nginx as a proxy server.
What the proxy server does is,when a user enters the website URL,I want to identify how to check if the request comes from my application i.e **app.mysite.com**(This won't change) and route it to apache for regular access,if its coming from some other domain like a regular URL www.mysite.com(This needs to be handled dynamically.Can be random) it goes to the S3 bucket that hosts the template.

My current configuration is:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

charset   utf-8;
keepalive_timeout  65;
server_tokens       off;
sendfile            on;
tcp_nopush          on;
tcp_nodelay         off;
```

## Default Server Block to catch undefined host names

```
    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name  app.mysite.com;

       access_log  off;
       error_log off;

      location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_redirect          off;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_connect_timeout 90;
        proxy_send_timeout 90;
        proxy_read_timeout 90;
        client_max_body_size 10m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_buffer_size 4k;
        proxy_buffers 4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
      }
 }
```

}

## Load all the sites

```
    include  /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

**Updates as I was not clear enough :-**
My question is how can I handle both the domains in the config file.My nginx is a proxy server on port 80 on an EC2 instance.This also hosts my application that runs on apache on a differnet port.So any request coming for my application will come from a domain `app.mysite.com` and I also want to proxy the hosted templates on S3 which are inside a bucket say `sites.mysite.com/coolsite.com/index.html`.So if someone hits `coolsite.com` I want to proxy it to the folder `sites.mysite.com/coolsite.com/index.html` and not to app.syartee.com.Hope I am clear

**The other server block:**

```
     # Server for S3
server {
    # Listen on port 80 for all IPs associated with your machine
    listen 80;

    # Catch all other server names
    server_name _; //I want it to handle other domains then app.mysite.com

    # This code gets the host without www. in front and places it inside
    # the $host_without_www variable
    # If someone requests www.coolsite.com, then $host_without_www will have the value coolsite.com
    set $host_without_www $host;
    if ($host ~* www\.(.*)) {
       set $host_without_www $1;

    }

    location / {
        # This code rewrites the original request, and adds the host without www in front
        # E.g. if someone requests
        # /directory/file.ext?param=value
        # from the coolsite.com site the request is rewritten to
        # /coolsite.com/directory/file.ext?param=value
        set $foo 'http://sites.mysite.com';
       # echo "$foo";
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $foo/$host_without_www$1 break;


        # The rewritten request is passed to S3
         proxy_pass http://sites.mysite.com;
         include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
   }
}
```

Also I understand I will have to make the DNS changes in the cname of the domain.I guess I will have to add `app.mysite.com` under the CNAME of the template domain name?Please correct if wrong.

Thank you for your time

Comment: My question is how can I handle both the domains in the config file.My nginx is a proxy server on port 80 on an EC2 instance.This also hosts my application that runs on apache on a differnet port.So any request coming for my application will come from a domain `app.mysite.com` and I also want to proxy the hosted templates on S3 which are inside a bucket say `sites.mysite.com/coolsite.com/index.html`.So if someone hits `coolsite.com` I want to proxy it to the folder `sites.mysite.com/coolsite.com/index.html` and not to app.syartee.com.Hope I am clear.Also updated the question with the same

Comment: ie. paste the files: /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf

Comment: I need help with the other server block,I am not sure if I am right,but I have added it above.@nandoP Both the blocks are in my `nginx.conf` file. i.e etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you config the server_name, nginx will serve the content based on config block that match the domain.

**app.mysite.com**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name  app.mysite.com;

  # config for app.mysite.com

}
```

**other websites**

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server; #To handle domains apart from the fixed domain(In my case app.mysite.com)
  server_name _ ;

  # config for coolsite.com, anotherdomain.com ...

}
```

Comment: Thank you bgentil,for the answer but the issue is `coolsite.com` is going to be configured dynamically by the user.It won't be known beforehand to us.So,I want the second server block to handle anything other than app.mysite.com`.I am not sure but if I make the first server the default one `listen 80 default_server;` in this way will it handle the requests correctly?

Comment: Yes you should use `listen 80 default_server;` in the block that will handle all requests that not match app.mysite.com. The behavior is described here http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html and here http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html